# Binary asset accessible from Javascript, without going through XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, arraybuffer

I would like to access an arbitrary binary file from JavaScript. I've found documentation which recommends going via `XMLHttpRequest`, an array buffer, and `Uint8Array`, like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "file.img", true);
req.responseType = "arraybuffer";

req.onload = function () {
    var arrayBuffer = req.response;
    if (arrayBuffer) {
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        // use bytes for the remainder of the program
    }
}
req.send(null);
```

However, I would like to access `file.img` without going through `XMLHttpRequest`, for two reasons:

- I would like it to work fully locally, i.e. if both the page and `file.img` are accessed via `file:` URIs
- The asynchronous nature of `XMLHttpRequest.send`/`XMLHttpRequest.onload` is a needless complication for my case, since `file.img` is <100k in size.

So all in all, I am looking for a way to include this binary asset `file.img` somehow in my page in the same way as one would include, for example, an image with a synchronous `img` tag.

Comment: Using a `file:` URI limits your options **markedly**. I can't think of a way to actually include a random data file in a page you're loading that way. So that means you'd basically have to embed `file.img`'s data *in* the JavaScript rather than having it separate — which isn't really "including" the binary asset in your page, it's including a *copy* of the binary asset in your page. Strongly recommend using a simple, small, local webserver and XHR instead.

Comment: Actually, turning it into javascript ahead-of-time (using something like `xxd -i` and a bit of post-processing) might not be such a bad idea for my use case.

Comment: Cool, that's probably the way to go then.

Comment: I'm happy to accept that suggestion (even though you don't approve of it:) ) if you post it as an answer :)

Comment: Oh, I don't have any problem with doing it that way. :-) I just didn't think it was an answer to the question, since it's not really including the file, it's including the data from the file (so if the file changes, the page's copy becomes out-of-date).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing the binary asset in a base64-encoded JavaScript string literal, importing that using `<script src=...>`, and accessing it using [`base64-js`](https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js).

I convert, ahead of time, the binary data into a JavaScript file with the following Make rule:

```
%.img.js: %.img
    (echo "var image64 = \"\\"; \
    base64 $< | sed -e 's/$$/\\/'; \
    echo '";') > $@
```

The `sed` line is needed to add `\` to the end of each line to make it into a single string.

Then, accessing it from JavaScript is a simple matter of using `base64-js` since it already has a function that decodes base64-encoded strings into an `Uint8Array`:

```
<script src="js/base64js/base64js-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="mydata.img.js"></script>

var imageArray = base64js.toByteArray(image64);
```